# When do bugfixes appear in ubuntu repositories?

Tags: linux, kde-plasma, ubuntu

For a specific bug on
https://bugs.kde.org/
the messages show that the bug was fixed and commited to the source repository. But when will the bugfix appear in the ubuntu repositories. Is there a fix shedule for bugfixes which allows me to estimate how long I need to wait for a specific bug?

Comment: This would be better asked on [AskUbuntu.com](http://www.AskUbuntu.com/) I would think.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about bugfixes in Ubuntu repositories, and would thus be better answered over at [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless it's a crucial security fix, the next Ubuntu upgrade is the earliest possibility. If it's a minor fix with big usability or compatibility implications, you can request a backport, or hope that somebody has rolled a PPA with the fix included. Individual bugs are tracked and prioritized in Launchpad, so for a start, make sure it's also reported there.